# Draw a n x n square but with a special rule

Tags: c

> Given two number N and K, output three squares with the size N x N each with their own set of rules:
> The first square is made entirely using the '#' symbol.
> The second square is made using the '.' symbol except for every k rows use the'#' symbol instead.
> The third square is made using the '.' symbol except for every k columns use the '#' symbol instead/
> Also print new line after printing each square.

I already know how to draw a square/shape(Hollowed or filled), but I'm still struggling with this one. Need help for the coding in C language. Thank you!

Comment: "I already know how to draw a square/shape(Hollowed or filled)" Show a [mre] of that, to show your own effort and to provide a foundation for answers.

Comment: If you know to print a square and you look at your code for that, can you identify the piece of code which makes a line/row? That would get you close to creating the second square. At first try to skip (i.e. not print) a certain row. Do that before thinking about the third square (which is trickier but should be easier once you achieved the second square).

Comment: Well, your printing function has a loop within a loop. The inner loop is for the columns and the outer loop is for the rows. You have to set the printing character in one loop or the other.

Comment: @enhzflep Wait .... you mean you need two loops to do the first square? ;-) I was assuming OP uses the single loop approach... Maybe we should look at a MRE after all.

Comment: Okay thanks for the feedbacks, I'm new to programming so sorry if its looked like I'm only begging for the answers without giving my own effort, I just don't have anyone else who knows how to code so my last option is to ask here.

Comment: Asking as a beginner here is fine. Just take the [tour] and read [ask]. Show your own work by providing a [mre] of doing square 1, and ask an actual focused question on something which has you stuck on the way between having achieved square 1 and failing to do square 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint.  Your basic "print me a square structure of size N x N" is normally like this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
           char c = '#';
           printf("%c",c);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Now what can you do to modify the code to take into account a different character should be printed for every Kth column or row?

Here's another hint.  To decide if `row` was a Kth row or not, you'd probably use this expression to test:

```
if (((row+1) % K) == 0)
```

The +1 takes in account that the loop counting starts at 0 instead of 1.

Comment: I am not voting, but I am a little unhappy with this answer giving (most of) the MRE I expect from OP to set their question apart from a do-my-homework question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int n = 10;
    int k = 3;
    char b[n+1];
    char s[n+1];

    ((char*)memset(b, '#', n))[n]=0;
    ((char*)memset(s, '.', n))[n]=0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", (i+1)%k? b : s);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5452KB
##########
##########
..........
##########
##########
..........
##########
##########
..........
##########
```

The matrix is 10x10, and every 3rd line is drawn with `.` instead of `#`.

Comment: Haha. :) CodeGolf's over that-a-way -----------> https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: :-) I am smiling at this homework trap (in at least two ways), because it is the opposite of the problem I have with the other answer. But seriously, do not be that underhandedly mean with poor homework-needers.... I am still code-parsing to convince myself this is allowed by the way ... so - my respect.

Comment: Maz Diaz, if you decide to use this as the second part of your assignment, hand it in, are asked to explain it ...... and actually succeed. Then you probably will not have to ask any other question for your homeworks in that class again. Or to put it differently: Don't.

Comment: Thanks for answers and the advices, It means a lot to me. Next time I'll put my own answers first and then ask the part where I'm confused/having trouble with. I'll be sure not to make the same mistake again.